# Is there a way to disable the Windows 11 Upgrade offer from the Autounattend.xml on a fresh Windows 10 install?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, unattended, autounattend

I have a Windows 10 USB that I use to automate Windows installations, and I'd love to be able to disable the Windows 11 Upgrade offer without having to do the really bad workarounds like using GPO (whether local or Active Directory) of locking the system(s) to a specific version, or completely disabling Windows Updates.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do, or even as a "first-run" option? Or am I stuck with 2 crappy options that will probably bite me in the rear-end later?

Comment: Why are you against using a group policy, that is designed to keep you on a specific version, if the specific version is the last version that will be released for Windows 10?  The correct way to handle this problem is with a group policy. There is literally a group policy that will keep you on the version you are on currently, allow updates to that version to be installed, allowing you to upgrade to the version you want when you want.  I am not sure what you mean by "first-run" option.  Care to explain?

Comment: I would set the `TargetReleaseVersion` to `1` and `TargetReleaseVersionInfo` to `21H1` and once 21H2 is released change it to `21H2` and call it day.  However, I am not aware of a "Windows 11 upgrade offer" existing at this time.  Microsoft is slow walking the upgrade to Windows 11, an upgrade to Windows 11, should only happen if you go seek it out.  If you are trying to prevent users from installing it, as an Administrator, use a group policy to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound Because I have a some systems that aren't on the domain, and aren't readily available to be updated/changed when the version changes. First-run, was meaning to be run the first time that someone logs into the machine after it's been setup. And, yes, the GPO method you described was the method I was speaking of (which is already configured as a GPO on our domain). I was just hoping for a way to disable it like we were able to with W7 to W10 initially.  
  
I just ran updates on one of the non-domain computers, and it offered the update to W11.

Comment: The method for Windows 7 required a registry key.  So why can’t you use the keys I suggested to do the same, now? You can always use semicolons and list to versions I believe